# Animated Div Overlay on Direction aware hover, with jQuery & CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

Just trying to develop a portfolio page similar to http://www.lippincott.com/work/ .

But, how to implement this Overlay Effect (please see the portfolio items in above URL) which is displayed / animated overlay according to the direction of mouse on hovering an element, say DIV.

Comment: with css opacity set at 95% and jquery .animate to move the div around

Comment: the exact logic is to implement this direction aware hover with jQUery and then accordingly animate the overlay made with css3. That's all I know - and I am stucked now. Not finding any common solutions or ready-made jQuery plugins for this one

Comment: thanks @frenchie but how to detect the mouse direction in jQuery and trigger the animation of div accordingly in that direction..that is the confusion

Comment: Did you try out the jsfiddle?

Comment: ah yes, I missed that. I'm off for a few days but the way to do this is to a) detect mousemove and use that to determine which direction the cursor is going and then b) set one css width or height to 0 and the other to the width or height of the container according to the direction previously determined and c) animate the 0 value to its full width/height.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a plug-in! **Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8pCw/11/) that redoes the same effect.**

```
<div id="BigDiv">

    <div class="MyWrapper">
        <div class="MyContent">5</div>
        <div class="MyOverlay"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="MyWrapper">
        <div class="MyContent">5</div>
        <div class="MyOverlay"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="MyWrapper">
        <div class="MyContent">5</div>
        <div class="MyOverlay"></div>
    </div>

</div>​
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.MyWrapper{
    margin:3px 3px;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:2px solid green;}

.MyContent{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;}

.MyOverlay{
    opacity:0;   
    width:0px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    left:0px;
    background:blue;}
```

Here's the javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        PageHandler();
    });

    function PageHandler() {

    $('#BigDiv').on({

        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.MyOverlay').css({
                opacity: '0.5',
                width: '0px'
            }).stop().animate({
                width: '50px'
            }, 500);
        },
    }, '.MyContent');

    $('#BigDiv').on({

        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.MyOverlay').each(function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    opacity: '0'
                }, 300, function() {
                    $(this).css('width', '0px');
                });} 
            )}
    }, '.MyWrapper');
}
```

I left the opacity at 0.5 instead of 0.95 so that you can see the 5 underneath better; it'll look better when you'll put a picture instead. You can also ply with the durations of the animations. But overall, it's the same effect; you just need to make it work with your design. **No plugin**, just jquery.

Answer (score 0):

There's an article published on tympanus.net that describes how this works:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

It's a simple plugin you can use, all you have to do is set up your css properly. It basically checks your mouse offset from when you enter and leave the hovered element, based on that it will decide from what side to animate the hover in.

Comment: Can you share your code that doesn't need CSS3? The link is no longer active. Thanks.

Comment: I have removed a dead link from this answer. If you have a piece of code that can be added directly into the question Tosh, please add that, to avoid further broken links. Thanks!